# Selenium Internet Explorer Control Click not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have IE 11. I am using the ie driver 3.14 32bit and writing my test in java. My os is win 10.

When I click on an element it works fine:

```
linkElement.click();
```

When I control click on the element it acts as if it is just a click:

```
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(linkElement).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

My goal is to open the link in a new tab - that is why I am control clicking. How do you open a link in a new tab in ie?

EDIT
Here is a simple test:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
URL driverUrl = TestTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("IEDriverServer.exe");
String driverPath = driverUrl.getPath();
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath.toString());
InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.cnn.com");
WebElement linkElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav\"]/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]")); // get World link
new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(linkElement).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

With my simplified test it opens in a new window - I have the setting in IE to open in a new tab. How can I make it open in a new tab?

Comment: What happens with _GeckoDriver_ and _ChromeDriver_? Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: Works perfect with GeckoDriver and ChromeDriver. Just IE - pain in the you know what

Comment: Update the question with the defination of `linkElement` and the relevant _HTML_

Comment: added an example

Comment: But which _link_ are you trying to click? The _xpath_ which you have used `//*[@id=\"nav\"]/div[2]/div[2]/a[2]` doesn't identifies any element on `https://edition.cnn.com/`